# Macaw php router 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I'm trying to use Macaw router that I downloaded and put the file `Macaw.php` in the same folder as `index.php`. In `index.php` I have this code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'Macaw.php';
use \NoahBuscher\Macaw\Macaw;

Macaw::get('/hello', function() {
    echo 'hello';
});

Macaw::get('/', function() {
    echo 'hello';
});
Macaw::dispatch();
```

and I created a .htaccess file in the same folder putting this code in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When I open the site in browser it shows me "hello" in the main route *('/')* but when I go to */hello* it show 404 Not Found error.

*-I'm using apache2 from the ubuntu repository*

*-[Macaw github repository](https://github.com/noahbuscher/Macaw)*

Comment: If it's in the same folder why are you declaring it's not?replace require_once 'odda/Macaw.php'; with require_once 'Macaw.php';

Comment: sorry I forgot to delete it after pasting from original code... I just put them in the same folder to make it easy for helpers to help

Comment: Replace `RewriteBase /macaw` in .htaccess with `RewriteBase /`